# In java, when a query is passed for fetching the Avg of a field from teradata,the decimal points are lost

Tags: java, teradata

I am passing the below query through my selenium java script.

```
SELECT avg(Field1) as Avg_Field1,Field2 
FROM table where PRIMARYVENDORNUMBER=81997 group by Field1,Field2
```

When I run this query in teradata my output is 7.00 , 0.00
But the output from my script is 7,0.00

So when I use the avg function I am losing the decimal points in the output that my script gives.

Note: my script truncates decimal points only when avg function is used.

```
String sql = query;
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
metadata = rs.getMetaData();
while (rs.next())
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= metadata.getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        Db_datas.add(rs.getString(i));
    }
    System.out.println(Db_datas);
}
```

Comment: `AVG` returns a `FLOAT` by default, so you might need to `CAST(avg(Field1) AS DEC(15,2))`

Comment: Thanks!! My issue is resolved

Comment: @dnoeth Please post your comment as an answer so Aish can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast the avg ...SELECT cast(avg(Field1) as decimal(7,2)) as Avg_Field1,Field2 FROM table where PRIMARYVENDORNUMBER=81997 group by Field1,Field2

Comment: Dnoeth give some sometime to others to solve the issue...:)

Comment: @Anwar - Dnoeth provided me a solution so fast that I was able to complete my task in office itself :) However thanks for posting the query for me.

Comment: @Aish: Just upvote this answer, it's correct (maybe increase the precision of the AVG so it doesn't fail) and it was not much slower than my comment :-)